# Reflection not fully implemented in Android 2.2?

Tags: android, reflection

I have some code that runs fine in 2.3 and above. However, in 2.2 I get an NullPointerException when className is getting assigned:

```
if(field.getType() == java.util.ArrayList.class)
   className = ((ParameterizedType)field.getGenericType()).toString();
```

**EDIT**

I did some snooping around on the android docs and found that some of the methods are not available until API level 9. However, getType(), getGenericType(), and ParameterizedType are all said to be supported at API level 1. So why doesn't this code work?

Field docs: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/reflect/Field.html

ParameterizedType docs: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/reflect/ParameterizedType.html

**EDIT**

I found out that calling field.getGenericType() does not cause the program to crash, but silently throws a com.sun.jdi.InvocationException. It seems like the Type returned from the call to getGenericType() is not valid? Again, this works on 2.3 and above, but why is this exception being thrown and caught on 2.2 and below?

Comment: It would be easier for us if you tell us, which object/call causes the NPE.

Comment: @WarrenFaith On the line where classname =...

Comment: and which call/object on that line? It could be `field` that is null, or `getGenericType()` returns null so that the cast and `toString()` throws the NPE. Be as specific as possible please.

Comment: @WarrenFaith I've updated the question. field was never null though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a known issue, here is the ticket in the Android bug tracker: [Issue 6636: NPE in org.apache.harmony.luni.lang.reflect.ListOfTypes](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=6636)

It was fixed in Android 2.3 but has not been backported to earlier Android releases which is why you see the crash in Android 2.2.

To be more elaborate: if you run this code (an extended version of your own code) on Android 2.2 :

```
public class ReproduceBugActivity extends Activity {
  private static final String TAG = "ReproduceBugActivity";
  private ArrayList<Object> mArrayList;

  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    try {
      String className = null;
      Field field = getClass().getDeclaredField("mArrayList");
      if (field.getType() == java.util.ArrayList.class)
        className = ((ParameterizedType)field.getGenericType()).toString();
      Log.i(TAG, "className = " + className);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

You will get this exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
   at org.apache.harmony.luni.lang.reflect.ListOfTypes.length(ListOfTypes.java:47)
   at org.apache.harmony.luni.lang.reflect.ImplForType.toString(ImplForType.java:83)
   at com.reproducebug.ReproduceBugActivity.onCreate(ReproduceBugActivity.java:23)
```

because of the above mentioned bug in the Java reflection implementation. On Android 2.3, the bug has been fixed, and you'll see this in the logcat instead:

```
I/ReproduceBugActivity(23449): className = java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.Object>
```

The `com.sun.jdi.InvocationException` exception your are seeing is unrelated to this as far as I can tell.

Comment: Try putting this line in your code: Type type = field.getGenericType();. When I hover over it during debugging, the rawType variable in type is null, but it seems to have the correct rawType name. However, it says the method invoked the com.sun.jdi.InvocationException. I think the NPE is from the toString() method being called on the object. Also, the error you linked to was kind of vague and I didn't get much from it. I'm assuming this is not going to be fixed at any point, but I'm still wondering why it can't be fixed or if there isn't a workaround.

Comment: I tried what you suggested, and now I see what you mean with "com.sun.jdi.InvocationException". That is just Eclipse's way of saying "I couldn't invoke toString() on the object you hover because I get a NPE". The bug report I linked to was mostly for reference. As a work-around for the bug, you could try to avoid using generics for fields you use reflection on, because then Type.toString() won't crash. You could also try to avoid Type.toString().

Comment: Good stuff. Probably the best answer I'm going to get. Really wish bugs like this would be easier to get answers on, or at least would be commented on in the SDK docs.